# LimitIterator Class Instead of array_slice

Tags: php, spl

During the study of SPL I saw LimitIterator, that Get a piece of array.

```
// Create an iterator to be limited
$fruits = new ArrayIterator(array(
    'apple',
    'banana',
    'cherry',
    'damson',
    'elderberry'
));

// Loop over first three fruits only
foreach (new LimitIterator($fruits, 0, 3) as $fruit) {
    var_dump($fruit);
}

string(5) "apple"
string(6) "banana"
string(6) "cherry"
```

But Why I Have to use SPL LimitIterator and create a Class, e new Istance of ArrayIterator, When I can Get the same result with simple array_slice?

```
$array = array('apple','banana','cherry','damson','elderberry');

foreach( array_slice($array,0,3) as $value ){
    var_dump($value);
}

string(5) "apple"
string(6) "banana"
string(6) "cherry"
```

Comment: Because array_slice works only with arrays while LimitIterator works on Iterators (and ArrayIterator just being _one_ of them). So the answer is: because they are different beasts.

Comment: @VolkerK, yes it's very simple :) . Thanks